# Table prints multiple column headers while filtering results

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

How can I stop my table from printing multiple column headers after I filter my results??  Example like shown below
[image: Multiple Headers printed]

My code

```
function fillQueryData() {
                $dbName = $_REQUEST ['db'];
                $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', $dbName );
                if (! $link) {
                        die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
                }
                if (isset ( $_POST ['name'] )) {
                        $name = trim ( $_POST ['name'] );
                        $tblName = $_REQUEST ['tbl'];
                        $colqry = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tblName'";
                        $col_names = mysqli_query ( $link, $colqry );
                        while ( $col = mysqli_fetch_array ( $col_names, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
                                $colName = $col ['COLUMN_NAME'];
                                $tblQry = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE $colName='$name' LIMIT 15";
                                $query2 = mysqli_query ( $link, $tblQry );

                        echo "<table><tr>";
                        $i = 0;
                        while ( $i < mysqli_num_fields ( $query2 ) ) {
                                $meta = mysqli_fetch_field_direct ( $query2, $i );
                                echo "<th>" . $meta->name . "</th>";
                                $i = $i + 1;
                        }
                        echo "</tr>";

                        $i = 0;
                        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row ( $query2 ) ) {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                $count = count ( $row );
                                $y = 0;
                                while ( $y < $count ) {
                                        $c_row = current ( $row );
                                        echo "<td>" . $c_row . "</td>";
                                        next ( $row );
                                        $y = $y + 1;
                                }
                                echo "</tr>";
                                $i = $i + 1;
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
        }       }
        }
```

I didn't want to put the table data while loops inside my column name while loop but if I don't I wont get any results in the rows. How can I work around this issue so only the filtered results are displayed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column header loop should be outside the data-fetch loops

Code should be like this.

```
function filterTblData() {
    $dbName = $_REQUEST ['db'];
    $link = mysqli_connect ( '192.168.2.113', 'root', '', $dbName );
    if (! $link) {
        die ( "Connection failed" . mysqli_errno ( $link ) );
    }
    if (isset ( $_POST ['name'] )) {
        $name = trim ( $_POST ['name'] );
        $tblName = $_REQUEST ['tbl'];
        // Dynamically select the column names of the chosen table.
        $colqry = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tblName'";
        $col_names = mysqli_query ( $link, $colqry );
        $col = mysqli_fetch_array ( $col_names, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
        $colName = $col ['COLUMN_NAME'];
        // Selecting and filtering results based on matching search terms.
        $tblQry = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE $colName='$name' LIMIT 15";
        $query2 = mysqli_query ( $link, $tblQry );

        echo "<table><tr>";
        // Loop for fetching table column headers and riprinting them.
        $i = 0;
        while ( $i < mysqli_num_fields ( $query2 ) ) {
            $meta = mysqli_fetch_field_direct ( $query2, $i );
            echo "<th>" . $meta->name . "</th>";
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        // Fetch row data and populate
        while ( $col = mysqli_fetch_array ( $col_names, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ) {
            $colName = $col ['COLUMN_NAME'];
            // Selecting and filtering results based on matching search terms.
            $tblQry = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE $colName='$name' LIMIT 15";
            $query2 = mysqli_query ( $link, $tblQry );
            $i = 0;
            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row ( $query2 ) ) {
                echo "<tr>";
                $count = count ( $row );
                $y = 0;
                while ( $y < $count ) {
                    $c_row = current ( $row );
                    echo "<td>" . $c_row . "</td>";
                    next ( $row );
                    $y = $y + 1;
                }
                echo "</tr>";
                $i = $i + 1;
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
filterTblData();
```